# timer is not stopped when it reaches zero

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a timer that when it reaches zero it stops. I've tried to make it with a clearInterval but it is not working. As it does nothing.

```js
function startGame() {
  var minute = 00;
  var sec = 10;
  const timeInterval = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("gameTimer").innerHTML =
      minute + " : " + sec;
    sec--;
    if (sec == 00) {
      minute--;
      sec = 59;
      if (minute == 00) {
        minute = 0;
        clearInterval(timeInterval)
      }
    } else if (minute == 0 && sec == 1) {
      document.getElementById("finishGame").innerHTML = "hello"
    }
  }, 1000);
};
```

```html
<span id="gameTimer"></span>
 <button onClick="startGame()">Start Counter</button>
<span id="finishGame"></span>
```

Comment: `minute` starts on 0, has 1 taken away from it (minute == -1) and then gets checked if it is == 0, which is false. A simple change is try `if (minute < 0) {` instead

Comment: Having said that, a better structure in general for this sort of thing is to only count in seconds, and the minutes:seconds is just how the time remaining is _displayed_. It'll make your logic quite a bit simpler overall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `minute <= 0` condition, since you subtract one from minute first, and then check for `minute == 0`, which will be false, since `minute` will be `-1`.
Also, its better to put all `if` conditions first, then subtract one from `second`.

```js
function startGame() {
  var minute = 0;
  var sec = 10;
  const timeInterval = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("gameTimer").innerHTML = minute + " : " + sec;
    if (sec <= 0) {
      minute--;
      sec = 59;
      if (minute <= 0) {
        minute = 0;
        clearInterval(timeInterval)
        }
    } else if (minute == 0 && sec == 1) {
      document.getElementById("finishGame").innerHTML = "hello";
    }
    sec--;
  }, 1000);
};
```

```html
<body>
  <span id="gameTimer"></span>
  <button onClick="startGame()">Start Counter</button>
  <span id="finishGame"></span>
</body>
```